# Simple note taking app on Ubuntu that allows markdown and copy paste of tables in spreadhseet format

Tags: text-processing, text-editor, text

(tag suggestions welcome)

I've been exploring note taking apps, including those listed [here](https://linuxstans.com/best-note-taking-apps-for-linux/) and [here](https://itsfoss.com/note-taking-apps-linux/). Preference is a foss app. I installed Simplenote which seems nice but already does more than I need. I was really seeking something like Geddit but with some minor text editing and formatting ability. I'd like something close to Google Docs, but not Google and where I can take simple notes including indenting, lists / bullet points, paragraphs etc.

I tried using Geddit but if for example I type a indented bullet point, the nextline does not auto indent - it's really for writing code it seems.

My main use case is taking fly notes while on calls, I'm seeking minimal to 0 time messing with logins, syncing or any other bells and whistles.

Somehting I commonly do though is paste a table from a spreadshet to a note, till now Gdocs. I can do this in markdown using an in between tool such as [table to markdown](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/) where I paste my table into their site and they generate the markdown whcih I can then copy paste into my notes.

Seeking recommendations, do any simple, lightweight note taking apps exist that support markdown AND would, either nativley or via a plugin, allow me to copy paste a table from a spreadsheet directly?

Comment: IMO the closer to what you want is `retext`, though not a note taking app. You can install it by `sudo apt install retext`.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity This looks pretty good actually. Pretty much perfect except one small thing - table formatting. Looks like copy pasting tables in there does not format as well as other tools out there. But still looks like the best fit

Comment: You can add a style sheet, for example bootstrap, adding the html header to the top of the file, and changing to the webkit engine option available in the *Edit* menu.

Comment: For example, add [the link provided by bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/getting-started/introduction/#css) to the top of the file, mark the option *Edit → Use WebKit renderer* and the html will be rendered with the boostrap css style.

Comment: I found a solution after fiddling around - I used edit > webkit renderer and the table formatted just as desired. This is perfect now, thanks for the tip!

Comment: Good editor to try is MarkText. See https://github.com/marktext/marktext .